# Oracle Query - retrieve the next row

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking to retrieve records based on condition
For eg if there is a table with 4 cols emp_id, emp_name,emp_sqc_num & emp_status.
Say the status has values 1 & 2. If there is only one record the emp_sqc_num will be 1 and status will be 1. If there are two records, then for emp_sqc_num 1 the status will be 2 and emp_sqc_num 2 the status will be 1.
Now I want to retrieve emp_id, emp_name,emp_sqc_num only for status with 1.

Comment: What's the part causing you difficulty?

Comment: what i am looking for is, the result set should have columns from table a and b. b has multiple records out of which one record which is the latest record with a particular status should be retrieved

Answer (score 1):

use the where clause to retrieve data with status 1

```
SELECT emp_id,emp_name,emp_sqc_num
FROM employee_table
WHERE emp_status=1;
```